# how to pass key value pair to dwr using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a piece of code like,

```
var jObj = {"key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"};
```

What I want to do is, I want to pass this as a parameter of DWR call like this,

```
dwrClass.dwrMethod(jObj);
```

Is it possible?